# Android: Getting the x/y coordinates of a double-tap?

Tags: java, android, gesture, ondraw, gesturedetector

I'm build an app that draws a circle to the screen when the user double-taps an image. I want the circle to appear at the exact x and y coordinates where the user taps the screen. RIght now, it draws the image at the top right of the screen. Do I have to implement onTouchEvent and how do I do that?

Here is the On Touch Listener: (touch is an imageview)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_display);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(ImageDisplayActivity.KEY_PATH);
    try {
        java.io.FileInputStream in = this.openFileInput(path);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
        touch = (ZoomInZoomOut)findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID);
        touch = arrangeImageView(touch);
        touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        in.close();
        touch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new
                    GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector(context));
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the class that is supposed to draw the circle

```
class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public Context context;

    public MyGestureDetector(Context con)
    {
        this.context=con;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
         Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
         bitmap.getHeight(),
         bitmap.getConfig());
         Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
         Paint p = new Paint();
         p.setAntiAlias(true);
         p.setColor(Color.RED);
         p.setStrokeWidth(2);
         p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,new Matrix(),null);
         canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(),event.getY(),
                100, p);
         touch.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: You just need to attach the touch to an object. is touch a object?

Comment: @Xjasz, 'touch' is an imageView...how can I attach the touch to an object?

Comment: Make sure that image view is filling the parent width and height in your resource file.

Comment: Yes, the imageView width and height is set to "match_parent" in the XML file

Comment: Does it just not paint anything?

Comment: It paints a circle but in the top right corner only...It doesn't always draw it in the same spot...it moves based on where I tap but it's always near the top right of the screen. I updated the code above with the full Oncreate method...